# Bouncy-castle integration in Websphere causing the following error

Tags: java, websphere, payment-gateway, bouncycastle

I am trying to configure bouncycastle in IBM Websphere App Server 7, my JRE Version is 1.6. I am getting the following error when trying to run the code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.Sun
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:511)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:543)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
                ... 47 more
```

I have tried the following:

1. Placing bcprov-jdk15-145 in jre/lib/ext
2. Placing bouncycastle-1.20 in project lib.
3. Adding the following entry at the end in java.security file - 
    security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
4. Placed Sun JSSE jars in server's Runtime Folder

Answer (score 0):

Refer to example provided in http://www.jasypt.org/non-default-providers.html.  Somewhere you have to code to choose the provider as BouncyCastleProvider in your code.  Currently by default it is not picking that.

Answer (score 0):

**Third party JCE Providers (including Sun JCE)** are **[not supported](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21107270)** in IBM WebSphere Application Server.

Get ready for *weird* issues in your server if you continue using them...